# How to plot the slope (tangent line) of parabola at any point?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a simple illustration of using derivative to find out a slope of a function at any point. It would look kinda like this:

[image]

I have already plotted a simple parabola using this code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

inputs = 0.2
weights = np.arange(-6,14)
target_prediction = 0.7

prediction = inputs*weights
errors = (prediction - target_prediction) ** 2
plt.xlabel("Weight")
plt.ylabel("Error")
plt.plot(weights, error)
```

Now I want to add something like this:

```
current_weight = 5
# draw a short fraction of a line to represent slope
x = np.arange(optimal_weight - 3, optimal_weight + 3)
# derivative
slope = 2 * (inputs*current_weight - target_prediction)
y = slope*x # How should this equation look like?
plt.plot(x, y)
```

To draw a tangent line going through the `current_weight`.

But I can't seem to figure this out, can you help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you have the slope at the desired point, you need to write the equation for the tangent line using point-slope form:

```
# Define parabola
def f(x): 
    return x**2

# Define parabola derivative
def slope(x): 
    return 2*x

# Define x data range for parabola
x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)

# Choose point to plot tangent line
x1 = -3
y1 = f(x1)

# Define tangent line
# y = m*(x - x1) + y1
def line(x, x1, y1):
    return slope(x1)*(x - x1) + y1

# Define x data range for tangent line
xrange = np.linspace(x1-1, x1+1, 10)

# Plot the figure
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.scatter(x1, y1, color='C1', s=50)
plt.plot(xrange, line(xrange, x1, y1), 'C1--', linewidth = 2)
```

[image: Parabola with tangent line]

You can do this for any differentiable function, and can use derivative approximation methods (such as finite differencing) to eliminate the need to provide the analytical derivative.

Comment: I have issue calculating slope of a curve with big data. I normalize values but they still have unit problem. resulting tangent values are disproportionate. how do you deal with your values? should I `np.tan(value * math.pi)` once more?